# How to perform Sum on a Map Key in the Mongo DB document within Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb-java

My MongoDB document looks something like as following:

```
{
"_class" : "com.foo.foo.FooClass",
"_id" : ObjectId("5441948f3004e65fbda72d9c"),
"actionType" : "LOGIN",
"actor" : "bolt",
"extraDataMap" : {
   "workHours" : NumberLong(11869) 
},
```

}

Where extraDataMap is a HashMap stored from the java code. I have to get all the documents where "actionType" is "Login", group on "actor" and sum all the "workHours" for those individual actors

If I do below query on MongoDB directly it works:

```
db.activityLog.aggregate([
{$match : { actionType : "LOGIN" }},
{$group : { "_id" : "$actor",  "hours" : {  "$sum" : "$extraDataMap.workHours" }  } },
{$sort : {_id : 1}}
]);
```

But If I run the query from Java Code

```
TypedAggregation<ActivityLog> agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(ActivityLog.class,
            buildCriteria(),
            group("actor").sum("extraDataMap.workHours").as("hours"),
            sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, MongoActivityLogRepository.DOCUMENT_ID_FIELD_NAME)
    );
AggregationResults<ActivityLog> result = mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, ActivityLog.class);
List<ActivityLog> results = result.getMappedResults();
```

It gives below error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property work found for type java.lang.String
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.<init>(PropertyPath.java:75)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:327)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:353)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:307)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.create(PropertyPath.java:290)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:274)
at org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyPath.from(PropertyPath.java:245)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.TypeBasedAggregationOperationContext.getReference(TypeBasedAggregationOperationContext.java:91)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GroupOperation$Operation.getValue(GroupOperation.java:359)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GroupOperation$Operation.toDBObject(GroupOperation.java:355)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GroupOperation.toDBObject(GroupOperation.java:300)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.toDbObject(Aggregation.java:228)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1287)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1264)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.aggregate(MongoTemplate.java:1253)
```

Really appreciate all the prompt responses :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem than you and I found this solution

Instead of using TypedAggregation, use a plain Aggregation. This way, spring data won't perform a type checking.

It would be as follows:

```
Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        buildCriteria(),
        group("actor").sum("extraDataMap.workHours").as("hours"),
        sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, MongoActivityLogRepository.DOCUMENT_ID_FIELD_NAME)
);

List<ActivityLog> results = mongoOperations.aggregate(agg, mongoOperations.getCollectionName(ActivityLog.class), ActivityLog.class).getMappedResults();
```

See that I used a different mongoOperations.aggregate signature, because since we are not using a TypedAggregation, we have to indicate over which collection we are performing the aggregation.

I hope this helps you.